# unittest library is not executing in mentioned selenium pythonscript

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I am trying create a unittest testcase in selenium python using Pycharm IDE , code is not working

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import unittest

class GoogleSearch(unittest.TestCase):

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    cls.driver.maximize_window()


@classmethod
def setUpClass(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    self.driver.get("https://google.com")
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("BT Plc")
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()

def setUpClass(self):
    self.driver.get("https://google.com")
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys("Nasir")
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("btnK").click()

@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.driver.close()
    cls.driver.quit()
```

print("Test completed")

script supposed to open google and search the mentioned element instead execute last line only

Comment: You can not have multiple methods with the same name in one class.

Comment: i have tried to run same code through cmd and getting below error                            ERROR: googleSearch (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
ImportError: Failed to import test module: googleSearch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 153, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\danish\PycharmProjects\MyProject\Webdriver_manager\SmallProject\googleSearch.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named selenium
Ran 1 test in 0.000s